# pdf 2 xhtml/css

Tags: css, pdf, xhtml

There are a lot of tools that convertes from pdf to html:  like this http://www.shareup.com/PDF_to_HTML-download-50574.html and there are others convert from html to css.

Is there a direct converter from pdf to xhtml/css files?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pdf-to-html.com/
If you can find good PDF to HTML converters, then you can easily convert HTML into XHTML using Tidy and others.

Comment: yes you are right, but I need to generate an external css file also, so I need a converter which generate html + css files from pdf file

Comment: Well, it looks like we do not have many choices in this direction. Converting from a print-based document to a HTML based document is not an easy one.

Comment: look, originally I need to convert svg file format to xhtml and css separated files , but unfortunately I also didn't find any successful solutions, so I turned to try to convert svg to either ps,pdf or  even to eps then to xhtml/css.

Comment: yes, I have tried it but this way doesn't convert the position of svg tag content in a right way, you know any svg tag may content transformation matrix to place the content correctly, and this way doesn't translate transformation matrix any more.